# Show only dates from current year using select in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to show dates from MySql from the current year in a comboBox.
I've tried using this code, but it doesn't work correctly, it ends up freezing.

```cs
 private void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            year_now = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd - MM - yyyy");
           string year2 = year_now.Remove(0, 10);
            string year3;
            string year4;
                
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                MySqlCommand busca_palestra = new MySqlCommand("Select tituloPalestra, diaPalestra from Palestras" , con);
                MySqlDataReader resultado = busca_palestra.ExecuteReader();

              
                    while (resultado.Read()) 
                    { 
                    year3 = resultado["diaPalestra"].ToString();
                    year4 = year3.Remove(0, 6);
                    while (year2 == year4)
                    {
                        comboBox1.Items.Add(resultado["tituloPalestra"].ToString());
                    }
                    }
                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
        }
```

[[image]]

Thank you for your time.

Comment: EndsWith returns a bool so your query would check if your "diaPalestra" is equal to either the string 'False' or 'True'.

Comment: EndsWith returns you a boolean. So what you are asking here via sql is if the diaPalestra contains "true" or "false". Is that what you want?  MAybe you want to start debugging your code first and look if your expectations are met. Don't just guess.

Comment: at first you can do this one : ```DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy")```. then in the loop you should add if statement to compare

Comment: Agreed, I think your SQL Statement should do a BETWEEN or <,>. (i.e. WHERE (diaPalestra >= '1/1/2021' AND diaPalestra < ' 1/1/2022'). You can also use a DISTINCT statement so you don't get duplicate dates.

Comment: Is diaPalestra actually a datetime? I have some doubts looking at the screenshot of your tables content.

Comment: It's a varchar, im trying to compare the last 4 caracters of the date( that would be the year) with the year of the computer, sorry if my explanations aren't very clear, i'm new to c# and english isn't my first language

Comment: Storing date values in a varchar is very big mistake. It breaks your ability to efficiently index or do date math on the column.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, the problem that this is a school project and is obrigatory to use it as a varchar

Comment: you should change that if you you can. Storing it as string and then splitting date and time into two columns will get you trouble in most simple requests. When you want to compare the last 4 chars you have to do it on the column also in MySql it should be something like `RIGHT(diaPalestra,4) = year`. And year is `Datetime.Now.Year.ToString()`

Comment: If you really must store it as a varchar, at least store it using the ISO8601 standard: `yyyy-MM-dd`, where everything is always ordered from most significant term to least: year, then month, than day (and so on from hours to milliseconds as well, when needed). This will at least allow you to index properly.

Answer (score 0):

Note: this will work, but it is also *so much slower* than it needs to be. If you can **fix** the schema for your column (because as it is the schema really is *broken*) then you can use indexes and real date operations on the column, which can make this at least a **full order of magnitude faster**, if not more.

How? Right now you must run this `substring()` call on *every row in the table*, even rows you don't care about, because until you run the function you can't know whether or not the row will match your condition.

If you have a real date column, however, you can index the column, which will allow you to jump almost directly to the part of the table where the rows will match the WHERE condition. Then, rather than running the substring call on each row you can write the query logically as two inequality checks (`>='20210101'` and `<'20220101'`), such that you're no longer mutating any stored data at all: it's just the conditional checks, which is far more efficient.

Therefore the choice is expensive function call for every row in the table, or cheap conditional checks for a few rows.

Additionally, it's poor practice to try to re-use the MySqlConnection object. The object you have in code is a lightweight wrapper around much heavier items managed by ADO.Net. When you try to re-use this object you make things slower, because you gained efficiency in the small thing while interferring with the code that already exists to manage the big thing. Instead, go ahead and create a brand new MySqlConnection for each query; it really is more efficient that way.

```
private void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sql = "SELECT tituloPalestra FROM Palestras WHERE substring(diaPalestra,7,4) = @year";      
    try
    {
        using (var con = new MySqlConnection("connection string here"))
        using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@year", DateTime.Now.Year.ToString());
            con.Open();

            using (var resultado = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (resultado.Read())
                {
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(resultado["tituloPalestra"].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }
}
```